# Create sharepoint workflow using xoml file

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-server

How can i create a xoml file contains all activities of SharePoint Workflow such as: SendEmail, CreateTask, OnTaskChnged ....

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to create xoml file dynamically, contains workflow activities, and assign this file to create a workflow instance.

Comment: kindly check this link: 
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/880ebdda-1ac6-425a-be1d-9ce64299a4a6/compiler-errors-when-calling-webpartpageswebservicevalidateworkflowmarkupandcreatesupportobjects?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy
I'm using sharepoint webservice to create and add workflow template, I need to create xoml file: XML that represents the definition of the workflow schedule; how can I do it dynamically using custom class in C#?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guide for 2007: http://agiledirect.wordpress.com/2008/07/04/packaging-and-re-using-sharepoint-designer-workflows-part-1/ where you will be able to find the .xoml file

And here for 2013: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj819316(v=office.15).aspx (note that it will be a .wsp file).

Steps:

> 1. Open an existing workflow, or develop a new workflow, in SharePoint Designer 2013.
> 2. On the Workflow Settings tab in the ribbon, click the Save as Template button in the Manage section as shown in the figure.
>
> [image]
>
> 3. An informational dialog box appears to let you know the template has been saved to the Site Assets library.
> 4. Click the Site Assets library to view the workflow template as shown in the figure.

The link also contains information regarding how to move this template to a new site collection and activate it

Comment: I need samples how can i use the objects model in C# to create this file (by serialize & deserialize methods)

Comment: That's not at all part of your question

Comment: just i need how can I create this file dynamically using C#, do you have any idea?

Comment: kindly check this link: 
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/880ebdda-1ac6-425a-be1d-9ce64299a4a6/compiler-errors-when-calling-webpartpageswebservicevalidateworkflowmarkupandcreatesupportobjects?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy
I'm using sharepoint webservice to create and add workflow template, I need to create xoml file: XML that represents the definition of the workflow schedule; how can I do it dynamically using custom class in C#?